# pyplot.plot() modifying line color cycle

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot some data obtained through measurements each with their fit.
I will plot 6 measurements on each figure, but I want each measurement data plot have the same color as its fit. From one measurement data plot to the next I want the defalut color cycle of matplotlib.

First, the data if loaded as following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
data1 = np.genfromtxt('data1.txt')
fit1 = np.genfromtxt('fit1.txt')
...
```

Then the problem, I can of course redefine the colour sequence in rcParams, like the following:

```
ColourSeq = []
ColourSeqOriginal = mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']
for ind in range(len(ColourSeqOriginal)):
    ColourSeq.append(ColourSeqOriginal[ind])
    ColourSeq.append(ColourSeqOriginal[ind])
mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ColourSeq
```

but this seems complicated.

The simplest thing seems to be:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xdata, data1, xdata, fit1, '???')
plt.plot(xdata, data2, xdata, fit2, '???')
plt.plot(xdata, data3, xdata, fit3, '???')
```

'???' being the command option which I don't don't know if some exists that will prevent plt.plot incrementing the color value for the given data.
But from one plt.plot() invocation to the next, I need to have the normal color increment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the color cycle on a per-axes basis

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_color_cyle(['r','r','b','b',..])
```

A cleaner way do to this is:

```
import itertools
colors_ = ['r','b','g','m','k'] # change to what colors you want

datas = [data1, data2, data3]
fits = [fit1, fit2, fit3]
ax = plt.gca()
for d, f, c in zip(datas, fits, itertools.cycle(colors_)):
    ax.plot(xdata, d, color=c)
    ax.plot(xdata, f, color=c)
```

This gives you control over exactly which colors get used, and if you decide to change how you are plotting your data and fit, you only have to change it once, not N times.  You can also easily add extra lists (like a list of labels, marker types, line styles ect) to control how your lines are plotted.  (the itertools.cycle is there to make sure the colors is never the limiting iterable in the `zip`).

The auto-cycling is good for prototyping, but you should get in the habit of specifying the colors for actual plotting.

Comment: An interesting point is that matplotlib uses itertools.cycle() to cycle through the default colors in rcParams.

Comment: @user1850133 indeed, thanks.  You can also suggest edits through the interface (and you get rep for it).

Comment: As soon as I posted my comment, I noticed you corrected your post by adding that missing 'in' ans so I removed my comment. Next time I will keep it on.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single argument to `plot()` that will force the same color for all lines in a single call to plot().  The only way to prevent the color cycle from incrementing is to specify the color using `color='x'`.

Here is an alternative approach that may work for you:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(xdata, data1)
ax.plot(xdata, fit1, color=ax.lines[-1].get_color())
ax.plot(xdata, data2)
ax.plot(xdata, fit2, color=ax.lines[-1].get_color())
ax.plot(xdata, data3)
ax.plot(xdata, fit3, color=ax.lines[-1].get_color())
```

By specifying the `color` of the fit lines, the color cycle is not incremented on the 'fit' data.

Comment: could you make your suggestion more consistent? what's ax? get_color()?

Comment: I apologize, `ax` is the axes on which you're plotting.  `get_color()` just returns the color attribute from a line.

Comment: That is matching very much what I was looking for, though I was expecting a simpler command than color=ax.lines[-1].get_color(). Anyway, that's matplotlib... Thanks.